# Can the DOL add an External API solution for IRC 6621 Table of Underpayment Rate quarterly updates

Tags: api, labor

As a financial service provider dealing with qualified defined contributions, we support clients in VCP corrections. Assisting in the DOL Calculations at scale for large participant base corrections would be ideal to have an external API developed to verify the latest updates for the (a)(2) Underpayment Rate and the (c)(1) Underpayment Rate tables.

Answer (score 0):

You need an external API to verify updates for (a)(2) and (c)(1) Underpayment Rate tables, aiding DOL calculations for VCP corrections. Steps include accessing data source, designing API endpoints, retrieving and updating data, supporting calculations, implementing authentication, providing documentation, testing, and deploying with monitoring.